# gnu-calc: How to declare variables in R (Real)?

Tags: variables, calc

I'm figuring out complex algebraic calculation in `gnu-calc`.

Suppose:
after many long calculation I got following algebraic expression:

`-8 * a - 2 * b + 2 * b * i - 40 * i - 8`

and I want the imaginary part of above expression so I do
`f i` (`M-x` `calc-im`) .

`-8 * im(a) - 2 * im(b) + 2 * re(b) - 40`

Of course above is correct, However I want to `a,b` have a Real Values (i.e. `im(a) = 0`, `im(b) = 0`) for further calculations. So desired output for above is: `2 * b - 40`.

---

**Question**: How to declare variables (in this case `a` and `b`) in Real number such that their imaginary part is 0 (for algebraic calculation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Gnu-Calc manual 6.6.1](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/calc.html#Declaration-Basics):
`calc-declare-variable` (keybinding: <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd>) is used for declaring variable to be `real`, `int`, `pos` or within range of something e.g `[0 .. inf)`.

In above case:

- <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> `a` <kbd>RET</kbd> `real` <kbd>RET</kbd>: makes variable `a` to be `real`
- <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> `b` <kbd>RET</kbd> `real` <kbd>RET</kbd>: makes variable `b` to be `real`.

After that, the imaginary part of  `-8 * a - 2 * b + 2 * b * i - 40 * i - 8` evaluates to `2 b - 40`.

---

Apparently, another more convenient option is `calc-edit-Decls` (keybinding: <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>). It will take you to matrix where you can edit all variable-declarations in one place:

```
Editing variable ‘Decls’Press ‘C-c C-c’ to finish, ‘C-x k RET’ to cancel.

[ [a, real],
  [b, real],
  [C, pos] ]
```